# What should I be doing to ensure the toolbar sits at the bottom, irrespective of the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, swift2, toolbar

I have created a view (MyOverlayView.xib) and add a toolbar to the bottom of the view and set the constraints to (left: 0, bottom, 0: right: 0) and I now add this to a UIImagePickerController, in my view controller, as such:

```
let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
if (cameraController != nil) {
    cameraController!.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    cameraController!.sourceType = .Camera
    cameraController!.cameraCaptureMode = .Video

    cameraController!.allowsEditing = false
    cameraController!.delegate = self
    cameraController!.showsCameraControls = false


    self.myOverlayView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MyOverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! MyOverlayView)

    if (self.myOverlayView != nil) {            
        self.myOverlayView!.frame = self.view!.frame            
        myOverlayView?.delegate = self;         
    } else {
        print("view not loaded")
    }
}
```

The issue is that while it appears to be sitting at the bottom in the interface builder, it is sitting half off the screen on my phone. What should I be doing to ensure the toolbar sits at the bottom, irrespective of the device?

XCode 7.2.1, Swift 2, iOS 9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended resolving this by selecting the UIToolber item, in the view, and then in the "resolve auto layout issues" item clicked on the "reset to suggested constraints".